# Assigning time series prediction confidence interval array to pandas dataframe (Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pmdarima

I'm currently trying to fit an time series forecasting model using Auto_ARIMA from pmdarima with forecasted value and prediction confidence interval as output. But when i tried to assign the confidence interval output to pandas dataframe it give me some errors. Here's the code and the error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima import auto_arima

model = auto_arima(train, 
                   exogenous=df_train[exogenous_features],
                   start_p=1, start_q=1, d=n_adf, max_p=5, max_q=5,
                   trace=True, n_jobs = -1, error_action="ignore", suppress_warnings=True)

model.fit(train,
          exogenous=df_train[exogenous_features])

forecast, confint  = model.predict(n_periods=len(df_valid),
                                   return_conf_int=True, alpha=0.05,
                                   exogenous=df_valid[exogenous_features])
```

```
df_valid["Forecast_ARIMA"] = forecast
df_valid["Upper", "Lower"] = confint
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('Upper', 'Lower')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
KeyError: ('Upper', 'Lower')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    129         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
    130             raise ValueError(
--> 131                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
    132                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"
    133             )

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

really appreciate it if someone can help me on this, thank you very much